# createQuery is not valid without active transaction or invalid state, the connection object is closed

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have the following Java config file:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.blahblah")
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Import({ SecurityConfig.class })

public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/VacationDB;instance=SQLEXPRESS");
        dataSource.setUsername("bavarezul13");
        dataSource.setPassword("Scholl1313.");

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean  sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(getDataSource());
        sessionFactory.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("hibernate.cfg.xml"));

        return sessionFactory;
     }

    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
       HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);
       return txManager;
    }

}
```

My DAO implementation is annotated @Transactional and I have a method like this:

```
@Repository(value="VacationDAOImplHibernate")
@Transactional
public class VacationDAOImplHibernate implements VacationDAO{

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public VacationHibernate getVacation(int id) {

        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        //Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

        String hql = "from VacationHibernate v where v.id = :id";
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<VacationHibernate> listVacationHibernate = session.createQuery(hql).setParameter("id", id).list();
        VacationHibernate vh = listVacationHibernate.get(0);
        //tx.commit();
        session.close();

        return vh;
    }
}
```

If I create a transaction and commit it, everything works normally. If not, I get the error:`java.sql.SQLException: Invalid state, the Connection object is closed` if I delete the following line from hibernate.cfg.xml: `<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>` or `org.hibernate.HibernateException: createQuery is not valid without active transaction` with that line in hibenrate.cfg.xml.

It wouldn't have been a problem to begin and commit the transaction by myself, but `Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();` takes 6 seconds!!!(I have no idea why)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marius, you may also try setting up connection pooling in your application to improve database connection retrieval time, for example we use `DBCP2` for connection pooling as the given example below

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {

    final org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource dataSource = new org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/myproject-db");
    dataSource.setUsername("username");
    dataSource.setPassword("password");
    dataSource.setInitialSize(2 * 5);
    dataSource.setMaxTotal(2 * 50);
    dataSource.setLogAbandoned(true);
    dataSource.setMaxIdle(2);
    dataSource.setMaxConnLifetimeMillis(3 * 60 * 1000); // Milliseconds (3 minutes)
    dataSource.setPoolPreparedStatements(true);

    return dataSource;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works great this way, I thought I have defined the connection pool in hibernate.cfg.xml but I haven't. '<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>' should do the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my errors: I deleted `name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>` in hibernate.cg.xml, so I had the error: `java.sql.SQLException: Invalid state, the Connection object is closed` as I said in my question. 
Then I deleted `session.close();` and the error went away.

Everything works now and Spring is managing the transaction but it also takes a lot of time to open it. 
I suspect it might be a problem with the driver

```
<dependency>
          <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
          <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
          <version>1.3.1</version>
      </dependency>
```